# Is there any way i can change owl carousel autoplay direction in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently both of these owl carousels move in the same direction (right to left). My code looks like this,I want one of these carousels to move in the opposite direction (left to right) on autoplay. I couldn't find anything in the documentations.

```
  const imageSlider = datajson.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className="item cards">
        <img src={item.image} alt="" />
        <div className="body_text">
          <h5>{item.title}</h5>
          <p>{item.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <OwlCarousel
        className="owl-theme"
        loop
        margin={10}
        nav={false}
        autoplay={true}
        autoplayTimeout={2000}
        autoplayHoverPause={true}
        items={4}
        dots={false}
      >
        {imageSlider}
      </OwlCarousel>
      <br />
      <OwlCarousel
        className="owl-theme"
        loop
        margin={40}
        nav={false}
        autoplay={true}
        autoplayTimeout={2000}
        autoplayHoverPause={true}
        items={4}
        dots={false}
      >
        {imageSlider}
      </OwlCarousel>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1534 check this